# The Axiom of Choice and a definition of addition in a quotient space of a vector space

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, quotient-spaces

I am thinking about the Axiom of Choice and I am trying to understand the Axiom with some but a little progress.
Some time ago I could not understand why the obvious "proof" of the Axiom of Choice is not correct.
Namely, let $A_i$, $i\in I$, be a collection of nonempty sets; in what follows we assume that the index set $I$ is infinite.
We construct a choice function for this collection as follows.
Consider arbitrary $i\in I$.
Since the set $A_i$ is nonempty, $\exists x(x\in A_i)$.
By Existential Instantiation we get $a\in A_i$.
Set $f(i):=a$.
It is clear that $f$ is a needed choice function.
Certainly the argument above is **not correct**, otherwise the argument would prove the Axiom of Choice so it would not be an axiom.
**But why the argument is not correct?**
Now my imperfect understanding is the following.
We can indeed consider arbitrary $i\in I$.
We can indeed apply Existential Instantiation to get $a\in A_i$.
We can indeed write $f(i):=a$.
But this defines $f$ only at **one** point $i$.
**At arbitrary point, but only at one.**
So currently $f$ is not a choice function for the whole given collection of sets.
We can choose another index, say $j\neq i$, apply Existential Instantiation to get $b\in A_j$, and set $f(j):=b$.
But now $f$ is defined only at **two** points $i$ and $j$.
**At arbitrary two points, but only at two.**
So currently $f$ is not a choice function for the whole given collection of sets.
Continuing this line of reasoning, we can define $f$ at, say, 100 arbitrary points of $I$.
**At arbitrary 100 points, but only at 100.**
So currently $f$ is not a choice function for the whole given collection of sets.
Finally, we **cannot** continue this process indefinitely.
Why?
Because in mathematics a proof **must be finite**!
Indeed, a proof is a sequence of (number of statement, statement, justification), and
this sequence **must be finite**; the last statement is exactly what we wanted to prove.
In particular, in a proof we can use only a **finite number** of Existential Instantiations (as justifications).
So, we must stop at some step.
At this step $f$ is defined only at a finite number of points of $I$.
So $f$ **is not** a choice function for the whole given collection of sets!
Thus by the obvious argument above we do not get a choice function.

**Question 1:** is my understanding of the failure of the obvious "proof" of the Axiom of Choice right and complete, or perhaps I am wrong, or perhaps I am missing something?
I am also very very interested in opinions of other people on the failure of the obvious "proof" of the Axiom of Choice. **Please do not hesitate to write me your opinion**, here or on my e-mail ivanmath007@gmail.com.

Let my move to my second question.
It is about a definition of addition in a quotient space of a vector space.
So let $V$ be a vector space and $U$ be a subspace of $V$.
Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $V$ as follows: $x\sim y$ if $x-y\in U$.
It is easy to check that $\sim$ is indeed an equivalence relation on $V$.
Denote by $V/U$ the set of equivalence classes.
It is indeed a set, it follows from ZF axioms.
We want to define a vector space structure on the set $V/U$.
In particular, we want to define addition on $V/U$, i.e., we want to define a **function** $+:V/U\times V/U\to V/U$ which satisfies certain known axioms.
I will write $\varphi$ instead of $+$, and so we want to define a **function**
$\varphi:V/U\times V/U\to V/U$.
The standard way to do this is the following.
Consider arbitrary $\alpha,\beta\in V/U$.
Choose $x\in\alpha$ (by Existential Instantiation, because we have no canonical representative of $\alpha$) and $y\in\beta$ (also by Existential Instantiation).
Now define $\varphi(\alpha,\beta)$ to be the equivalence class of $x+y$.
Of course, it is easy to check that this equivalence class will be the same for any other representatives of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but we **need** to choose $x$ and $y$ to define it.
Thus we defined a function $\varphi$.
But now analyze this definition of the function $\varphi$.
**It is essentially the same as the construction of a choice function from the obvious "proof" of the Axiom of Choice**!
**Thus this definition of $\varphi$ is not correct, it does not define a function
$\varphi:V/U\times V/U\to V/U$**!
This makes me crazy.
I am used to the above definition of addition in a quotient space and I "believed" in it
for the last 15 years.
So it is hard for me, but I will ask:

**Question 2:** am I right that the above definition of the function $\varphi$ is not correct and it does not define a function $\varphi:V/U\times V/U\to V/U$?

Finally I should note that we can save the day --- define
$\varphi(\alpha,\beta):=\{x+y\,|\,x\in\alpha,y\in\beta\}$ for $\alpha,\beta\in V/U$;
of course one must check that for arbitrary $\alpha,\beta\in V/U$ the set
$\{x+y\,|\,x\in\alpha,y\in\beta\}$ is an equivalence class.
In spite of this, Question 2 **remains** very very important for me.

Despite the fact that this question turned out to be very long I hope it will be useful.
Once more, please do not hesitate to write me.

Comment: This feels like a stream of consciousness, not like a proper question. Especially since the "Question" parts depend heavily on the preceding paragraphs that are just huge chunks of text.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dear Asaf, if my question perhaps looks like a stream of consciousness --- ok, I will not argue with you. I have been writing this question for over three hours to make it **honest**, clear, and, as I hope, useful for other people who like me are trying to understand the Axiom of Choice. Definitely, I **need** help with understanding the Axiom of Choice and the websites MO and MSE are one of those few places where I can get such help. Clearly, this question is not for MO, so I decided to ask it on MSE. This is my chance to get help.

Comment: Ivan, you're just proving my point. Your comment reply *is* a stream of consciousness. Yes, this is probably the right website for this question. But frankly, I can't look at your question and immediately know what you're asking here. I can *guess* that you're a bit confused as to how we can define the addition in quotients without choosing representatives, but I have no idea.

Comment: If my guess was correct, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854959/how-do-we-define-functions-on-quotient-sets and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752373/is-the-axiom-of-choice-implicitly-used-when-defining-a-binary-operation-on-a-quo might be useful for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the reason the definition you give isn't quite proper has nothing to do with the axiom of choice. Rather, it's because a **definition** is not a **process**: if we want to be extremely precise, language like "Pick an $x$" has no place in a definition regardless of what we assume about choice, the issue being the word "Pick."

Here **is** a grammatically-valid definition:

> $\alpha\boxplus_\exists\beta=\gamma$ iff there are $x\in\alpha,y\in\beta$ such that $x+y\in\gamma$.

(I'm using the new "$\boxplus$" symbol for clarity.) And here's another one:

> $\alpha\boxplus_\forall\beta=\gamma$ iff for all $x\in\alpha,y\in\beta$ we have $x+y\in\gamma$.

Note that their equivalence is **not** logically trivial: in particular, without knowing anything about vector spaces I might worry that $\boxplus_\exists$ is actually multi-valued and $\boxplus_{\forall}$ is actually non-total. But this still has nothing to do with choice! **If $\boxplus_\exists$ were multivalued** then we might want to "refine" it to a single-valued function, and at this point choice and the question of its necessity could conceivably enter the picture. However, we can prove - without using choice at all - that this is not the case, so the issue doesn't arise in the first place.

*(Note that if we were really concerned about these issues we'd actually go one step further and avoid using function notation at all - we'd first consider e.g. the **formula** $\sigma_\exists(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\equiv\exists x\in\alpha,y\in\beta(x+y\in\gamma)$, and then show that this formula **defines a function** in the sense that $\forall \alpha,\beta\exists!\gamma(\sigma_\exists(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ - but this doesn't really add to the discussion above.)*

---

What about your original proposed "proof" for $\mathsf{AC}$? Well, again, natural language issues - in particular the intrusion of "imperative" language - are going to obscure the underlying formalism. I **strongly** recommend learning some particular formal proof system (e.g. sequent calculus) so that you can write and compare correct arguments with superficially-similar incorrect arguments.

(Meanwhile, one of the best sells for the axiom of choice in my opinion is that it makes imperative reasoning safer.)

Comment: Dear Noah, thank you very much for your answer. I would be very grateful if you could suggest me a book where I could read about sequent calculus (I wish the book was for beginners).

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko Sorry, I missed this comment originally! If memory serves, I learned from Enderton's book. Boolos/Burgess/Jeffrey is also quite good - the relevant part is the precise of first-order logic (occupying two quick chapters).